# Can access to SQL Server on many networks but not on a specific one

Tags: sql-server

I have SQL Server Express installed on a virtual machine (port 1433 opened).

I can access the database from many clients' WiFis, my home's WiFi, but never on our workplace's WiFi.

I have access to our router at our workplace; I checked and there are no restrictions. The firmware is also up to date (Linksys E900 router).

I have no idea why I can access on many other connections but not this one.

Comment: Where is the VM running? On your laptop, at work. or in the cloud?

Comment: Cloud (Amazon Web Services)